# ACF5: Use field names rather than field keys for HTML element IDs

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've taken over a plugin which relies heavily on Advanced Custom Fields. For further development I updated ACF from version 4 to the latest version (5.8.x).

The plugin includes styles and scripts relying on HTML element (e.g. input) IDs such as `acf-field-header_caption`, where `header_caption` is the field name. This works well with ACF 4, but in version 5, the much less coder-friendly field key (e.g. `5ac098bae96e4`) is used for the IDs and classes, eg: `acf-field-5ac098bae96e4`. (The custom fields are added to a post_type and edited on that post_type in the backend.)

Example:

Input field in ACF v4 (what I need):

```
<input type="text" id="acf-field-header_caption" class="text" name="fields[field_5ac098bae96e4]" value="" placeholder="">
```

Same field in ACF v5 (what I don't want):

```
<input type="text" id="acf-field-5ac098bae96e4" class="text" name="fields[field_5ac098bae96e4]" value="" placeholder="">
```

**Is there a way to revert back to HTML IDs in which the field names rather than the field keys are used?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Huebner answered this question on the ACF support forum (thanks!).

**There is no way to revert to the old class and ID format.** This means, you have to update custom scripts and CSS when updating to ACF 5.

If one prefers to use the field name rather than the field key for the likes of jQuery or CSS selectors, one could use the `data-name` attribute in the wrapper div. Example for a selector referencing header_caption input field from above:

```
[data-name="header_caption"] input
```

(This works well for text fields, radio fields and their likes have multiple inputs within the wrapper.)

I quote the original answer:

> No, there isn’t a way to revert the field ID values. The only place you will find the field name is in the wrapper div data-name="field_name_here".
>
> In addition to the change in IDs and classes, even changing them would likely not help with the JS. If the JS is dependent on ACFs JS then it probably will not work anyway. The JS in ACF5 is completely different than ACF4 and any custom JS that interacts with it would need to be completely rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

This forces the input id to be equal to the field name. But I guess it will break many things and I would not recommand to use it.

```php
add_filter(
    'acf/prepare_field',
    static function ($field)
    {
        $field['id'] = $field['_name'];
        return $field;
    }
);
```